# Castle Windsor: Cannot resolve Controllers

Tags: dependency-injection, castle-windsor

I'm trying to use DI (namely Castle Windsor) in my solution but I'm getting the following exception:

```
No component for supporting the service Company.Web.Controllers.DashboardController was found
```

This exception occurs in `WindsorControllerFactory.GetControllerInstance()` when trying to resolve the controller (ie: `(IController)_kernel.Resolve(controllerType);`)

**However,** when I move the DI installers and controller factory in to the asp.net application and have that web project reference all the projects in my solution, the exception does not occur.

**Question: How do I resolve the exception and above and have my dependency injection and its configuration into it's own assembly (ie: Company.Initialization)?**

Please feel free to provide any constructive criticism that will improve on the code.

**Current Solution Project setup**

1. Company.Initialization is in a assembly called Company.Initialization. This contains assembly contains the DI configurations and reference to Castle Windosr.
2. Company.Initialization has a reference to every assembly.
3. Company.Web is in an assembly called Company.Web
4. Company.Web is an ASP.NET MVC4 application.

**ControllersInstaller.cs**

```
namespace Company.Initialization
{
    public class ControllersInstaller : IWindsorInstaller
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Installs the controllers
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="container"></param>
        /// <param name="store"></param>
        public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
        {
            container.Register(FindControllers().LifestyleTransient());
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Find controllers within this assembly in the same namespace as HomeController
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private BasedOnDescriptor FindControllers()
        {
            return AllTypes.FromAssemblyNamed("Company.Web")
                 .BasedOn<IController>()
                 .If(Component.IsInNamespace(@"Company.Web.Controllers"))
                 .If(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Controller"));

        }

    }
}
```

**RepoInstaller.cs**

```
namespace Company.Initialization
{
    public class RepoInstaller : IWindsorInstaller
    {

        public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
        {
            container.Register(AllTypes.FromAssemblyNamed("Company.Services")
                .Where(type => type.Name.EndsWith("Service"))
                .WithService.DefaultInterfaces().LifestyleSingleton());

            container.Register(AllTypes.FromAssemblyNamed("Company.NHibernateProvider")
               .Where(type => type.Name.EndsWith("Repository"))
               .WithService.DefaultInterfaces().LifestyleSingleton());

        }
    }
}
```

**WindsorControllerFactory.cs**

```
namespace Company.Initialization
{
    public class WindsorControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory
    {
        private readonly IKernel _kernel;

        /// <summary>
        /// Constructor
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="kernel"></param>
        public WindsorControllerFactory(IKernel kernel)
        {
            _kernel = kernel;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Release the controller at the end of it's life cycle
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="controller">The Interface to an MVC controller</param>
        public override void ReleaseController(IController controller)
        {
            _kernel.ReleaseComponent(controller);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Resolve a controller dependency
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="requestContext">The HTTP context</param>
        /// <param name="controllerType">Type of controller to resolve</param>
        /// <returns>IController</returns>
        protected override IController GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
        {
            if (controllerType == null)
            {
                throw new HttpException(404, string.Format("The controller for path '{0}' could not be found.",
                    requestContext.HttpContext.Request.Path));
            }
            return (IController)_kernel.Resolve(controllerType);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Have you checked that all assemblies are indeed present in the directory from which the application is executing ? Could you check what happens if you individually register your DashBoardController component

Comment: It is not good practice to have Installers in separated project. They should be in your web app project.

Comment: @Marwjin: The assemblies are there.

Comment: @rarous: If I put the installer in the web project, then that means my web project would have to reference the data access layers which is not a good practice, no?

Comment: @burnt1ce it also has in your solution. Indirect, but has. Those are two different things to reference DAL and to call DAL from UI layer. Your web project is also a composition root of your application.

Comment: Stab in the dark. Do you need to specify DefaultInterfaces() or something similar on your controller registration so that it supports services other than IController?